# LaTeX calendar: how to force each month to be on a separate page

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, calendar, tikz-calendar

I have this simple code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \calendar
  [
    dates=2023-07-01 to 2023-09-last,
    week list,inner sep=2pt,month label above centered,
    month text=\%mt \%y0
  ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to have each month on a separate page? Can I put `\newpage` somewhere in the code?

Actually, I have a longer code, this is only MWE. I want to incorporate the desired answer into my larger project...

Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't (easily) split a tikzpicture across package. So instead of drawing everything in one tikzpicture, you could use a separate `tikzpicture` for each month:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

\foreach \mo in {07,08,09}{

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \calendar
  [
    dates=2023-\mo-01 to 2023-\mo-last,
    week list,inner sep=2pt,month label above centered,
    month text=\%mt \%y0
  ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks!!!!

Comment: @JoudaBouda You're welcome!